# Why do I get "Sort by another column" error Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I do not understand why do I get this error?

[image]

I know for sure that column `MM-DD Sort` has a unique values in a table

This is my query for calendar table that I am using in Power BI:

```
 DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2017-07-01',
        @MaxDate DATE = CAST(GETDATE() + 7  as DATE)  
;WITH cte_Calendar AS (
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
) SELECT Date,
         MonthNum = MONTH(Date)
         ,Year = Year(Date)
         ,Month = FORMAT(Date, 'MMM')
         ,'MM-DD' = FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') + '-'+ FORMAT(Date, 'dd')
         ,'MM-DD Sort' = FORMAT(Date, 'yyMMdd')

FROM cte_Calendar
```

So is it some kind of a bug in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `MM-DD Sort` are unique but the values in `MM-DD` are not.

For example, if your date table spans 2019 and 2020, then you'll have `Jun-30` in multiple rows with `190630` and `200630` in the sorting column. So Power BI doesn't know which index to use for sorting purposes.

You can use your suggested sorting column for dates (which do include year) but since there is no year in `MM-DD`, then you can't include the year in `MM-DD Sort` and expect it to work.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I thought  the goal of a sort column is actually to tell Power Bi how to order data when there is multiple rows ( such  with value `190630`). So there is no really way to sort it without  a year?

Comment: It's more so that your visuals will display the months sequentially rather than alphabetically.